# Understanding javascript closure variable capture in v8

Tags: javascript, closures, v8

I understand the semantics that a closure holds a reference to a variable lengthen it's life cycle, makes primitive variables not limited by calling stack, and thus those variables captured by closures should be specially treated.

I also understand variables in same scope could be differently treated depends on whether it was captured by closures in now-days javascript engine. for example,

```
function foo(){
    var a=2;
    var b=new Array(a_very_big_number).join('+');
    return function(){
        console.log(a);
    };
}
var b=foo();
```

as no one hold a reference to `b` in `foo`, there's no need to keep `b` in memory, thus memory used could be released as soon as `foo` returns(or even never created under furthur optimization).

My question is, why v8 seems to pack all variables referenced by all closures together in each calling context? for example,

```
function foo(){
    var a=0,b=1,c=2;
    var zig=function(){
        console.log(a);
    };
    var zag=function(){
        console.log(b);
    };
    return [zig,zag];
}
```

both `zig` and `zag` seems to hold a reference to `a` and `b`, even it's apparent that `b` is not available to `zig`. This could be awful when `b` is very big, and `zig` persists very long.

But stands on the point of view of the implementation, I can not understand why this is a must. Based on my knowledge, without calling `eval`, the scope chain can be determined before excution, thus the reference relationship can be determined. The engine should aware that when `zig` is no longer available, nether do `a` so the engine mark it as garbage.

Both chrome and firefox seems to obey the rule. Does standard say that any implementation must do this? Or this implementation is more practical, more efficient? I'm quite puzzling.

Comment: There is [a Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315190) on this, which has some informative comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't say anything about garbage collection, but gives some clues of what should happen.
Reference : [Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

> An outer Lexical Environment may, of course, have its own outer
>   Lexical Environment. A Lexical Environment may serve as the outer
>   environment for multiple inner Lexical Environments. For example, if a
>   Function Declaration contains two nested Function Declarations then
>   the Lexical Environments of each of the nested functions will have as
>   their outer Lexical Environment the Lexical Environment of the current
>   execution of the surrounding function."

```
Section 13 Function definition
  step 4: "Let closure be the result of creating a new Function object as specified in 13.2"

Section 13.2 "a Lexical Environment specified by Scope" (scope = closure)

Section 10.2 Lexical Environments:
"The outer reference of a (inner) Lexical Environment is a reference to the Lexical Environment that logically surrounds the inner Lexical Environment.
```

So, a function will have access to the environment of the parent.

Answer (score 3):

The main obstacle is mutability. If two closures share the same `var` then they must do so in a way that mutating it from one closure is visible in the other. Hence it is not possible to *copy* the values of referenced variables into each closure environment, like functional languages would do (where bindings are immutable). You need to share a pointer to a common mutable heap location.

Now, you could allocate each captured variable as a separate cell on the heap, instead of one array holding all. However, that would often be more expensive in space and time because you'd need multiple allocations and two levels of indirection (each closure points to its own closure environment, which points to each shared mutable variable cell). With the current implementation it's just one allocation per scope and one indirection to access a variable (all closures within a single scope point to the same mutable variable array). The downside is that certain life times are longer than you might expect. It's a trade-off.

Other considerations are implementation complexity and debuggability. With dubious features like `eval` and expectations that debuggers can inspect the scope chain, the scope-based implementation is more tractable.

Comment: Yes, my proposed way seems not compatible with `eval`, but `eval` is something I believe will one day disappear from javacript. And If there's no 'eval', since the inner closure environment will be completely stable, there's no need to save it. Each variable name should either be bound to a variable that can be determined at "compile time", or be regarded as a "free variable" in the outer most environment. Thus a second indirection is no needed. The variable name directly reference the shared mutable variable, and each variable is separately stored .

Comment: @YukiN, the indirection through a per-closure environment is needed regardless of `eval`, because the generated code cannot "directly reference the variable" -- it has to address a variable with an index that is invariant across closure instances. Also, `eval` cannot be removed without breaking the entire Web, so that will never happen.

Comment: `Function` is enough for most case. As `eval` is dangerous and can efficiently prevent optimization, and now there's a new indirect `eval`  semantics which behaves same as `Function`, I believe the current `eval` will eventually be replaced by the indirect `eval`.

Comment: @YukiN, oh, in case that wasn't clear, I completely agree that `eval` is bad -- and many other features of JS are, too. Yet, I can assure you (as a long-time member of TC39) that none of them will be removed from the language because backwards compatibility is not negotiable on the Web. FWIW, the Function constructor and indirect eval are not significantly better anyway.